# How do we get 3 prediction of regressions in one pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using SKlearn QuantileRegressor with the quantile values of [0.5, 0.1, 0.9] to get the predicted values with the upper and the lower confidence level of prediction. I am also using TransformedTargetRegressor to take care of target transformation. To get 3 prediction values in the Pipeline, I attempted to use FeatureUnion for parallel estimations

```
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())
        ('estimator', FeatureUnion([
                    ('regressor', TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=QuantileRegression(quantile=0.50), func=log_func, inverse_func=exp_func,check_inverse=True)),
                    ('regressor_lower', TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=QuantileRegression(quantile=0.10), func=log_func, inverse_func=exp_func,check_inverse=True)),
                    ('regressor_upper', TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=QuantileRegression(quantile=0.90), func=log_func, inverse_func=exp_func,check_inverse=True))
                ]))
    ])
```

I get error All estimators should implement fit and transform. What is the alternative to get prediction of three regressors.

Comment: `FeatureUnion` is meant for input feature union only. Currently, you can't have three estimators in single pipeline. I think, you have to manage it separately.

Comment: Thanks. Understand that `FeatureUnion` is defined for concatenating results of multiple transformer objects, not for estimators. A separate pipeline is workable, however painful.